# Copy properties from one frame to another

Tags: html, css

I am having difficulties copying properties from one fram and create a similar one (See picture below). The picture to the left, flower-ish, Is the properties I want. I wanna add this to the image to the right ( blue one). I have tried using the google chrome edit component but I can't figure it out.

I only want the image to the right to have the same properties (size and frame) as the left image.

[The URL to this scenario](http://www.shopstuff.se/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looking your page, i think you should do something like this (I'm using jQuery).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var img = $('.attachment-shop_catalog');
  var width = img.width();
  var height = img.height();

  //give an id or a class to identify your target img, i'm using id target-img 

  $('#target-img').css('width',width+'px');
  $('#target-img').css('height',height+'px');

});
```

Comment: Hi, How can I do this with HTML and CSS? I have never used jQuery. What  I would like is the HTML and the corresponding CSS :)

Comment: I don't think that you can do something like this with HTML and CSS only. You need Javascript.
PS: in your site you have already included jQuery.

Comment: If I use Javascript then, should I just copy and paste the above code in javascript? If you observe this site [link](http://www.coolstuff.se/) and scroll down and observe the + sign , that is what I am trying to accomplish.